# Misunderstanding of calculating gain of amplifier

Tags: amplifier, gain, unity-gain

I’ve been reading in my textbook that the gain is
Gain= Vout/Vin= 1+ Rf/Rin

However, what if there isn’t a resistor like this amplifier?
Would it be 1V/V or 2V/V? Or am I totally misunderstanding this?
Any help to clarify would be greatly appreciated
[image]

Comment: That symbol is a little weird. The way it's connected makes it seem like an op-amp, but its shape looks like a multiplexer. I think they should have just drawn it as a triangle.

Comment: No - it is not an opamp. It is an OTA with a current output (high impedance) - see my detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the equation like this: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That really clarifies it for me and makes sense!

Comment: always  Vin+=Vin- so = Vout

Comment: I cannot agree. Vin+ is not identical to Vin-. No virtual ground effect because it is not an opamp.

Comment: @LvW is this comment about my answer?

Comment: Andy aka - yes. In your comment I read Vin+=Vin-. But this does not apply here, instead we have Iout=gm*Vd with Vd=(Vin+) - (Vin-).

Comment: I think the OP mean it to be an op-amp!

Comment: Could be - but it is not. I am afraid, it is true when the OP says:  " Am I totally misunderstanding this?". It is the classical - commonly agreed - symbol for an OTA. Another indication: The load capacitor. This makes sense for an OTA (most important element for lowpass application), but it makes no sense in case of a unity-gain wired opamp.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the shown symbol represents an active device called "OTA" (Operational Transconductance Amplifier) with two high-impedance input terminals and one high-impedance output terminal.

The shown circuit is, normally, used as a tunable first order lowpass with the tranfer function:

**H(s)=1/[1+1/(gm*rout) + sC/gm]**

For gm*rout>>1 the function reduces to **H(s)=1/(1+sC/gm)**

The output resistance rout is included because in many cases it cannot be neglected. It is to be mentioned that the "gain" of the device (transconductance gm) cannot be idealized (like Aol for opamps).
Therefore, the diff. voltage at the input must not be set to zero (no "virtual ground" effect).

But the transfer function can be **tuned with gm** - a parameter which can be **externally varied** by a current Iabc (abc=amplifier bias current, separate pin not shown in the symbol).

**Comment**: Another versatile application of the OTA (without external elements) is a tunable grounded resistor. In this case, the non-inv. input is grounded. Then, the resistance betweeen the inv. input and ground is **rin=(1/gm)||rout**.

For more information:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj0krOs0JDtAhVE3aQKHQ3DAvYQFjAAegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.com%2Fcitations%3Fuser%3Df-GCFyQAAAAJ%26hl%3Den&usg=AOvVaw0o6nTVSw29c7br-wOtwm45